# Zapier Code: Python, generating a CSV string

Tags: python, python-3.x, zapier

I am trying to generate a simple csv string (not file!) with Zapier Code (Python).
The given code is working when I'm typing it in the Python REPL on my computer, but Zapier is telling me...

> 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'

which doesn't make any sense to me...

Anyone had this problem too and can give me a solution?

I Already printed out the python version, just to make sure this isn't the problem, it is Version 3.7.

```
import io
import csv
# root = ElementTree.fromstring(input_data['xml']);
stringio = io.StringIO()
fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
writer = csv.DictWriter(stringio, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
return stringio.getvalue()
```

Comment: What is your expected output? if you want to return this {'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'} then why are you writing it with csv.DictWriter?

Comment: In Zapier, the data you return at the end is the data you can work with in later steps. So the last statement should return the csv string...

Comment: What is a csv string? and in zapier the return should be json serializable and not some string so convert your csv into dict and then return it, but i still dont understand why are you writting it with csv.DictWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python Code by Zapier expects a `dict` output, you're returning a `str` (the error message could be better about this).

In any case, amend your code to the following:

```py
# ...
return {'result': stringio.getvalue()}
```

and that should work.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! This is indeed a really confusing error message. Also Zapier is just returning in all their examples instead of using output.